# FB.AppRequest - Not able to parse the users who were invited

Tags: facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

After doing a Fb.AppRequest, in my callback, I try to parse out how many users where invited by the user doing the invitation.

The problem I'm having, is that I'm parsing my result as follows:

```
var responseObject = Json.Deserialize(result.Text) as Dictionary<string, object>;
```

and when I try to access the "to" parameter, I cant get the value as an array. I tried the following, but it didnt work either.

```
        object obj = 0;
        if (responseObject.TryGetValue ("to", out obj))                                                              
        {      
            Debug.Log("Sent to: " + ((string[])obj).Length);                                                                                  
        }
```

Any help on how I can get the amount of users to which I sent the invite to?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to know how many objects do you have, you can cast that object to an IEnumerable for example:

```
IEnumerable<object> obj = (IEnumerable<object>)responseObject["to"];
int count = obj.Count();
```

or something like that.
Hope that helps !